# Attempt to re-open an already closed object error Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to build a simle to-do list app adds user input to listview but keep getting this error

```
public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            task.setTaskName(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setStatus(cursor.getInt(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            taskList.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return task list
    return taskList;
}
```

getting the error on this line SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_task);
    db = new TaskerDbHelper(this);
    list = db.getAllTasks();
    adapt = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_inner_view, list);
    ListView listTask = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listTask.setAdapter(adapt);
}
```

and here: list = db.getAllTasks();

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/activfy.activfy/databases/taskerManager
                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:263)
                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
                                                                 at activfy.activfy.TaskerDbHelper.getAllTasks(TaskerDbHelper.java:73)
                                                                 at activfy.activfy.GoalActivity.onCreate(GoalActivity.java:32)
```

edit:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TASKNAME
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    db.close();
}




 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: Post your sqlite helper `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()`. Guess you're closing the db there.

Comment: You need to close your cursor before you leave the method: `cursor.close();`

Comment: added onCreate() and onUpgrade codes. cursor.close(); didn't help, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();

String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  try {

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        task.setTaskName(cursor.getString(1));
        task.setStatus(cursor.getInt(2));
        // Adding contact to list
        taskList.add(task);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
 finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

// return task list
return taskList;
 }
```

And in your `OnCreat()` you should not close your DB.

Comment: cursor never will be null

Answer (score 4):

You should not be calling `close()` on the `SQLiteDatabase` passed to you in `onCreate()` as you don't own it.